# How to convert KerasTensor to numpy array

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

In Tensorflow 2 the output of a layer in functional API is a `KerasTensor`. How can I convert this `KerasTensor` to a `numpy` array? Methods such as `tf.make_ndarray()` or `x.numpy()` (x is a tensor) does not work. Both return the error that the `KerasTensor` does not have a `numpy` method.

Comment: Kindly, Have you found the solution to this problem? please let me know if so, i am really stuck to this problem and i would be so thankful for any advices.